# Notificaciones Push con App android Cerrada

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notificaciones

tal ves alguien que pudiera ayudarme con lo siguiente:

Necesito poder enviar Notificaciones Push aún cuando la aplicación haya sido eliminada cómo funciona **Whatsapp**. Tal ves pudieran recomendarme alguna información para solucionar este problema. 
Con Firebase no es posible, en algunos teléfonos como Xiaomi, Huawei, Lg, etc. 
Después de algún tiempo de inactividad de la aplicación o cuando esta pasa a segundo plano las notificaciones ya no llegan.

Actualmente el receptor de Notificaciones para Firebase lo tengo en un servicio
pero igual sucede lo mismo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: A que te refieres con eliminada? cuando la aplicación se destruye?, yo actualmente uso  Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) y estando la aplicación cerrada o en segundo plano me llega la notificación.

Comment: Si Adrian...intenta con un telefóno xiaomi o huawei. Deja tu aplicación en segundo plano o cierrala y espera un tiempo. Intenta mandar una notificación de datos y veras que no llega.

Comment: Actualmente hago pruebas con moto g6 plus, nexus 5, p20lite,galaxi A8, y la notificación llega.